# Adicionar botões na action bar quando se usa ListActivity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Bom tenho uma aplicação que gostaria de manter o formato padrão em todas as telas,
eu tenho um menu de acesso rápido com alguns itens na action bar, e outro completo na opção menu.

O problema é que como eu estou usando o `ListActivity` isso não esta funcionando.
não entendo muito bem essa parte de extensões, se alguém tiver um bom material que explica, em português por favor, eu agradeço.

[image: como eu queria que ficasse]

Meu código XML do menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.starlighting.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menugerenceditar"
        android:icon="@drawable/editar"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Editar"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuadd"
        android:icon="@drawable/site"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Gerenciar"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuremov"
        android:icon="@drawable/site"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="Importar"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuexportar"
        android:icon="@drawable/site"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:title="exportar"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuimportar"
        android:icon="@drawable/site"
        android:orderInCategory="5"
        android:title="Star Lighting"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menusair"
        android:icon="@drawable/sair"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Sair"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Meu código de *inflater* menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    if(featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null){
        if(menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")){
            try{
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            } catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
            } catch(Exception e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gerenciar, menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gerenciarescondido, menu);
    onMenuOpened(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR, menu);
    return true;
}

//seta as opções de função dos itens do menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menugerenceditar) {
        //List<Lista> lista = gerarlista(tabbanco);

        //final Listaadapter listasadapter = new Listaadapter(this,  lista);
        //setListAdapter(listasadapter); 

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            //Lista tabela = listasadapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(gerenciar.this, gerenciartabela.class);
            //intent.putExtra("tabela", tabela.getNome());
            startActivity(intent);
        }});
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.menuadd) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(gerenciar.this, adcionartabela.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    if(id==R.id.menuremov){
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.menusair) {
        AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = 
                new AlertDialog.Builder(gerenciar.this);

        mensagem.setTitle("Atenção!");
        mensagem.setMessage("Deseja realmente sair?");
        mensagem.setIcon(R.drawable.sair);

        mensagem.setPositiveButton("Sim",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                gerenciar.this.finish();
            }});
        mensagem.setNegativeButton("Não",null);
        mensagem.show();
        return true;

    }
    if (id == R.id.menuexportar) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.menuimportar) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Meu código 'lista'**

```
        package com.example.app;
    public class Lista {

        private String nome;
    //    private int idade;
     //   private int imagem;


        public Lista() {
        }

        public Lista(String nome) {
            super();
            this.nome = nome;

        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

          @Override
        public String toString() {
            return nome;
        }
    }
```

**Meu código 'lista adapter'**

```
    package com.example.app;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Listaadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lista> {

        private Context context;
        private List<Lista> lista = null;

        public Listaadapter(Context context,  List<Lista> lista) {
            super(context,0, lista);
            this.lista = lista;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            Lista tabela = lista.get(position);

            if(view == null)
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.lista, null);


            TextView textViewNomeLista = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textViewNomeLista.setText(tabela.getNome());


            return view;
        }
    }
```

**Meu código que trabalha com a lista**

```
    package com.example.app;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.ActionMenuChildView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class gerenciar extends ListActivity{
    boolean editar=false, adcionar=false, remover=false;
    SQLiteDatabase Banco = null;
    Cursor cursor;
    List<Lista> tabelas = new ArrayList<Lista>();
    String tabbanco="Tabela1";
    TextView gerenciar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gerenciamento);
        //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        gerenciar=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewgerenciar);
        gerenciar.setText("   Escolha a tabela que deseja trabalhar.");
        abrebanco();
        buscardados();
        List<Lista> lista = gerarlista();

        final Listaadapter listasadapter = new Listaadapter(this,  lista);
        setListAdapter(listasadapter); 


        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Lista tabela = listasadapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(gerenciar.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("tabbanco", tabela.getNome());
            gerenciar.this.finish();
            startActivity(intent);


        }
        });

    }

    public List<Lista> gerarlista() {
        //tabelas.add(criarLista("Tabela1"));
        cursor.moveToLast();
        int x=cursor.getCount();
        while(x>0){
        //nextdado();   
        tabelas.add(criarLista(retornadado())); 
        dadoanterior();
        x--;
        };
        return tabelas;
    }
    public boolean dadoanterior() {
        try{
            cursor.moveToPrevious();
            return true;

        }
        catch(Exception erro){
            return false;

        }

    }

    public boolean nextdado(){
        try{
            cursor.moveToNext();
            return true;

        }
        catch(Exception erro){
            return false;

        }
    }
    private Lista criarLista(String nome) {
        Lista tabelas = new Lista(nome);
        return tabelas;
    }
    public boolean buscardados(){
        try{
            cursor = Banco.query("tabela",
                    new String [] {"tabelas",}
            , null, null, null, null, null);

            if (cursor.getCount() != 0){
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            }else{
                String sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (tabelas) " +
                          "values (Tabela1) ";
                    Banco.execSQL(sql);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception erro){
            Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao buscar no banco: "+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
            return false;
        }
    }
    public String retornadado(){
        String dado = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tabelas"));
        return dado;
    }
    public void abrebanco(){
        try{
            Banco = openOrCreateDatabase("banco", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
            String sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabela (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
                    ", tabelas TEXT)";
            Banco.execSQL(sql);

        }
        catch(Exception erro){
            Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao criar banco: =/"+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        if(featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null){
            if(menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")){
                try{
                    Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    m.invoke(menu, true);
                } catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                } catch(Exception e){
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gerenciar, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gerenciarescondido, menu);
        onMenuOpened(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //seta as opções de função dos itens do menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.menuadd) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(gerenciar.this, adcionartabela.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            gerenciar.this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        if(id==R.id.menuremov){
            AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = 
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(gerenciar.this);

            mensagem.setTitle("Atenção!");
            mensagem.setMessage("Deseja realmente excluir uma tabela?" +
                    "\n Os dados contidos serão excluidos permanentemente!");
            mensagem.setIcon(R.drawable.sair);

            mensagem.setPositiveButton("Sim",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(gerenciar.this, excluirtabela.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    gerenciar.this.finish();


                }});
            mensagem.setNegativeButton("Não",null);
            mensagem.show();
            return true;




        }
        if (id == R.id.menusair) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = 
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(gerenciar.this);

            mensagem.setTitle("Atenção!");
            mensagem.setMessage("Deseja realmente sair?");
            mensagem.setIcon(R.drawable.sair);

            mensagem.setPositiveButton("Sim",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                    gerenciar.this.finish();

                }});
            mensagem.setNegativeButton("Não",null);
            mensagem.show();
            return true;

        }
/*      if (id == R.id.menuexportar) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(gerenciar.this, exportararquivo.class);
            //intent.putExtra("tabbanco", tabela.getNome());

            startActivity(intent);
            gerenciar.this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.menuimportar) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(gerenciar.this, importararquivo.class);
            //intent.putExtra("tabbanco", tabela.getNome());

            startActivity(intent);
            //gerenciar.this.finish();
            return true;
        }*/
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void Exibirmensagem (String titulo, 
            String texto, String button)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = 
                new AlertDialog.Builder(gerenciar.this);
        mensagem.setTitle(titulo);
        mensagem.setMessage(texto);
        mensagem.setNeutralButton(button,null);
        mensagem.show();
    }



}
```

Comment: Joannis está usando o `appcompat` para utilizar a ´ActionBar`? Se for infelizmente o `ListActivity` não tem relação com ele, logo não tem ´ActionBar`. O que você pode fazer é criar uma subclasse do `ActionBarActivity` e incluir as facilidades que o `ListActivity` trás, olhando o código fonte: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/app/ListActivity.java.

Comment: sim é isso mesmo, como eu faço isso?

Comment: Posso montar uma resposta a noite, mas a ideia é copiar o código do `ListActivity` e fazer uma subclasse de `ActionBarActivity`, para se ter as funcionalidades do `ListActivity` no `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: eu entendi a ideia, só não sei como criar uma subclasse, nem como usá-la, bom vou tentar se eu conseguir posto aqui a resposta, se não agradeço muito sua ajuda.vlw

Comment: Não precisa chegar ao ponto de copiar código-fonte de `ListActivity` (apesar de ser uma classe pequena), só fazer algo assim já é suficiente: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242136/how-can-i-implement-a-listview-without-listactivity-use-only-activity

Comment: É, copiar o código não vai ser simples. Tem um método que o `ActionBarActivity` deixou como `final` mas que o `ListActivity` usa... Acho que a idéia do @Piovezan é mais simples.

Comment: @wakim você pode me dar uma ajuda com isso?
eu deixei de lado por um tempo e agora ta pegando, (só falta isso)
olhei o link do piovezan mas não entendi direito. 
vou postar meus códigos na pergunta.

Comment: @Joannis, você precisa trocar a superclasse de `ListActivity` para `ActionBarActivity` e fazer os devidos acertos. Posso preparar uma resposta mais tarde, no momento estou meio enrolado no trabalho...

Comment: ok, tentarei fazer aqui, vou ver o que eu consigo, vou postando meu avanço. 
grato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sugeri anteriormente, a ideia é criar uma classe que herde de `ActionBarActivity` mas que tenha os métodos de suporte da classe `ListActivity`.

A classe seria essa:

```
public class ListActionBarActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    /**
     * This field should be made private, so it is hidden from the SDK.
     * {@hide}
     */
    protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
    /**
     * This field should be made private, so it is hidden from the SDK.
     * {@hide}
     */
    protected ListView mList;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private Runnable mRequestFocus = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    mList.focusableViewAvailable(mList);
            }
    };

    /**
     * This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.
     * Subclasses should override. Subclasses can call
     * getListView().getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the
     * data associated with the selected item.
     *
     * @param l The ListView where the click happened
     * @param v The view that was clicked within the ListView
     * @param position The position of the view in the list
     * @param id The row id of the item that was clicked
     */
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    }

    /**
     * Ensures the list view has been created before Activity restores all
     * of the view states.
     *
     *@see android.app.Activity#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
            ensureList();
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }

    /**
     * @see android.app.Activity#onDestroy()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRequestFocus);
            super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * Provide the cursor for the list view.
     */
    public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
            synchronized (this) {
                    ensureList();
                    mAdapter = adapter;
                    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
    }

    /**
     * Set the currently selected list item to the specified
     * position with the adapter's data
     *
     * @param position
     */
    public void setSelection(int position) {
            mList.setSelection(position);
    }

    /**
     * Get the position of the currently selected list item.
     */
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
            return mList.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    /**
     * Get the cursor row ID of the currently selected list item.
     */
    public long getSelectedItemId() {
            return mList.getSelectedItemId();
    }

    /**
     * Get the activity's list view widget.
     */
    public ListView getListView() {
            ensureList();
            return mList;
    }

    /**
     * Get the ListAdapter associated with this activity's ListView.
     */
    public ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
            return mAdapter;
    }

    private void ensureList() {
            if (mList != null) {
                    return;
            }
            setContentView(com.android.internal.R.layout.list_content_simple);

    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                    onListItemClick((ListView)parent, v, position, id);
            }
    };

}
```

Foi preservado o máximo do código que a `ListActivity` provê, porém apenas um método ficou de fora. Porque a `ActionBarActivity` sobreescreve o método `onContentChanged` de adiciona o modificador `final`, logo não é possível sobreescrevê-lo na classe criada.

Mas pelo seu uso, a `ListActionBarActivity` deve atender.