# Como utilizar ListActivity com ActionBar?

Tags: java, android, listview, actionbar

Só é possível acessar o menu de um `ListView` que está sem a `ActionBar` pela tecla do menu no emulador.

Como exibi-lo? É necessário inflar pelo `BaseAdapter`?

[image: ListView sem ActionBar]

`Activity` da `ListView`:

```
public class ListDespesasActivity extends ListActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    DespesaDAO despesa = new DespesaDAO(this);
    List<Despesa> list = despesa.getLista();
    ListView listView = getListView();
    setListAdapter(new DespesaAdapter(this,list,listView));


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_despesas, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_add_despesa:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditaDespesaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

`BaseAdapter`:

```
public class DespesaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<Despesa> lista;
private ListView listView;


public DespesaAdapter(Context context, List<Despesa> lista, ListView listView) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
    this.listView = listView;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final int auxPosition = position;




    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditaDespesaActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("valor", lista.get(auxPosition).getValor());
            intent.putExtra("data", lista.get(auxPosition).getData());
            intent.putExtra("descricao", lista.get(auxPosition).getDescricao());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });





    TextView data = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.ddata);
    data.setText(lista.get(position).getData());

    TextView desc = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.ddesc);
    desc.setText(lista.get(position).getDescricao());

    TextView valor = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.vvalor);
    valor.setText(lista.get(position).getValor());

    return layout;
}
}
```

`Manifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.prjctt.allan.financeiro" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditaDespesaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edita_despesa"
        android:parentActivityName=".ListDespesasActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ListDespesasActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListDespesasActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_despesas"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditaReceitaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edita_receita" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Allan, poderia incluir seu Manifest e seu arquivo de estilos?

Comment: Manifest incluido, o que seria o aquivo de estilos? @Wakim

Comment: O arquivo `styles.xml`.

Comment: Editado com o styles.xml @Wakim

Comment: Eu recomendaria mudar a superclasse da sua `Activity` para `ActionBarActivity`, mas isso vai fazer com que alguns métodos não estejam disponíveis (e.g: `setListAdapter`) mas ai é só você copiar e implementar você mesmo (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38337/adicionar-bot%C3%B5es-na-action-bar-quando-se-usa-listactivity/39384#39384).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma *Activity* para ter um *ActionBar* tem de descender de *ActionBarActivity*, o que não é o caso de *ListActivity*.

Uma Activity não necessita de derivar de ListActivity para que possa usar uma ListView.
A classe *ListActivity* existe apenas para facilitar o uso da *ListView* em uma *Activity*.

Para que a sua *ActionBarActivity* possa manipular uma ListView necessita de um  *Layout* que contenha uma e uma referência a ela.

Declare um campo privado para guardar a *ListView*

```
private ListView listView;
```

No método `onCreate` obtenha uma referência à *ListView* e use o método `ListView.setAdapter` para passar uma instância de `DespesaAdapater`

```
public class ListDespesasActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Layout que contem a ListView
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DespesaDAO despesa = new DespesaDAO(this);
        List<Despesa> list = despesa.getLista();

        // O mesmos que ListView listView = getListView();
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        //O mesmo que setListAdapter(new DespesaAdapter(this,list,listView));
        listView.setAdapter(new DespesaAdapter(this,list,listView));
    }
}
```

Agora a *ActionBarActivity* é uma *"ActionBarListActivity"*

Para interagir com a *ListView* use o campo listView:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) 
    {
        ....
        ....
     }
});
```

Apesar de esta solução ser de fácil implementação, o aconselhável seria a utilização de um *ListFragment* juntamente com a *ActionBarActivity*

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado, agora está tudo certo!