# Como tratar das opções da ActionBar?

Tags: android

Olá,
na app que estou a fazer todas as minhas actividades (exceptuando 2) tem o `extends` de uma outra Actividade (`BaseActivity`) onde eu faço o tratamento das opções disponiveis na `ActionBar`, com isto evito repetir o código em todas as actividades. Acontece que nessas 2 actividades em que não tenho esse `extends` eu tenho uma listview que é feita atraves de um Adapter (logo tenho de fazer `extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter` ).

A minha pergunta é, como é que eu vou tratar das opções disponiveis na ActionBar destas 2 actividades já que não posso fazer `extends` da `BaseActivity`? Tenho de repetir o código? Como costumam fazer?

**Exemplo:**
Todas as actividades estão assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {....}
```

exceptuando 2, que estão assim:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {...}
```

como faço para estas duas?
Obrigada!

Comment: `Adapter` não tem nada a ver com `Activity`, o que você deve estar perguntando é sobre `ListActivity`. Correto?

Comment: Possível duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38337/adicionar-bot%C3%B5es-na-action-bar-quando-se-usa-listactivity

Comment: @Piovezan com isto "Adapter não tem nada a ver com Activity" resolveste o meu problema. Estava a fazer confusão...a Actividade "chama" um Adapter para preencher a Listview. Eu estava a pensar que o Adapter era uma actividade :\  Obrigada!!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Achei que fosse o problema de activities estendendo `ListActivity`, que de fato impede que seja feito o `extends BaseActivity` ou `extends ActionBarActivity`. A solução nesse caso seria implementar a funcionalidade de `ListActivity` manualmente na activity, como indicado no link que passei. Fica o comentário para quem encontrar esta pergunta passando pelo segundo problema.